# How to detect same types of nodes touching each other consecutively (SpriteKit)

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, game-physics, skspritenode

Actually this is rather an algorithm and implementation problem.

I have an array of nodes, these nodes have 3 types. Their distinctive speciality is their color.

I want to detect that if a couple of same nodes is touching themselves consecutively to create a joint or something like it.

For example lets assume I have bunch of balls in my array which can be 3 colors red, blue, green. I want to find the joints which has 5 elements.

I tried recursive way of iterating through the array. But it sometimes works sometimes doesn't. So I think the way I'm doing has some flaws.

```
- (void) findAdjacentNode:(BallSpriteNode*) currentNode from:(NSMutableArray*)currentNodes{

    for (BallSpriteNode *node in currentNodes) {
        float distance = [self getDistanceBetween:node.position and:currentNode.position];

        if ( distance - (node.size.width/2 + currentNode.size.width/2 ) <= 0
            && [node.currentColor isEqual:((BallSpriteNode*)currentNode).currentColor]
            && ![node isEqual:currentNode]
            && ![sameColorNodes containsObject:node])
        {
            [sameColorNodes addObject:node];
            [self findAdjacentNode:node from:currentNodes];
        }
    }

    if (sameColorNodes.count >=5) {
        [self removeSelectedNodesFromArray:sameColorNodes];
        return;
    }
}
```

Appreciated for any kind of help and lead.

I've reached to solve my problem but still a little problem appears randomly. My `SKSpriteNode` subclass has `isRemoved` variable to track if node was removed. I see that my problem occurs removing the same nodes again and again, so infinite loop.

---

**EDIT:**
By changing my implementation like below I solved my main problem and it's already good.

```
if (sameColorNodes.count >=5) {
    bool isEligibleToRemove = YES;
    for (BallSpriteNode *node in sameColorNodes) {
        if (node.isRemoved) {
            isEligibleToRemove = NO;
            break;
        }
    }

    if(isEligibleToRemove){
        NSLog(@"%@",sameColorNodes);
        [self removeSelectedNodesFromArray:sameColorNodes];
    }
}
```

Right now I'm dealing with a problem which happens randomly and it is hard to catch. Sometimes my method fails to add some nodes to `sameColorNodes` array even they should be in it. For example if 9 of them forming a group it takes 8 of them in it. But it works right every time if it has 5 nodes.

---

**EDIT 2:**

This is the final version of my algorithm. I tested it and works fine. If you call this method for all the nodes in some array. It will find all the nodes that are the same colour and creating a path by touching each other.

```
- (void) findAdjacentNode:(BallSpriteNode*)currentNode from:(NSMutableArray*)currentNodes{

    recursiveCount ++;

    if(![sameColorNodes containsObject:currentNode]){
        [sameColorNodes addObject:currentNode];
    }

    for (BallSpriteNode *node in currentNodes) {
        float distance = [self getDistanceBetween:node.position and:currentNode.position];

        if (node.ballType == BrickBall) {
            continue;
        }

        if (distance - (node.size.width/2 + currentNode.size.width/2) <= 0
            && [node.currentColor isEqual:((BallSpriteNode*)currentNode).currentColor]
            && ![node isEqual:currentNode]
            && ![sameColorNodes containsObject:node])
        {
            [sameColorNodes addObject:node];
            [self findAdjacentNode:node from:currentNodes];
        }
    }

    recursiveCount --;

    if (sameColorNodes.count >=5 && recursiveCount == 0) {
        bool isEligibleToRemove = YES;
        for (BallSpriteNode *node in sameColorNodes) {
            if (node.isRemoved) {
                isEligibleToRemove = NO;
                break;
            }
        }

        if(isEligibleToRemove){
            NSLog(@"%@",sameColorNodes);
            [self removeSelectedNodesFromArray:sameColorNodes];        
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: why you don't just detact them in `-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event` that which node contacting with which node ?

Comment: because in my scenario I just have to wait until all the nodes have stopped.

Comment: It looks like you are doing many redundant compares. I would imagine the code won't scale well particularly since it is recursive.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE:**

The following groups sprites that are close in proximity and have the same `currentColor` property. It creates a dictionary that contains the sprite's index as the key and an array of matching sprites as the object:

```
- (CGFloat) getDistanceBetween:(CGPoint)point1 and:(CGPoint)point2 {
    CGFloat dx = point1.x - point2.x;
    CGFloat dy = point1.y - point2.y;
    return sqrt(dx*dx+dy*dy);
}

- (void) countMatches:(NSMutableArray*)currentNodes {
    NSMutableDictionary *colorCount = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    NSMutableArray *nodes = [currentNodes mutableCopy];
    for (NSUInteger i=0;i<nodes.count;i++) {
        BallSpriteNode *ball1 = [nodes objectAtIndex:i];
        NSNumber *key = [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInteger:i];
        for (NSUInteger j=nodes.count-1;j>i;j--) {
            BallSpriteNode *ball2 = [nodes objectAtIndex:j];
            float distance = [self getDistanceBetween:ball1.position and:ball2.position];
            if (distance - (ball2.size.width/2 + ball1.size.width/2) <= 0
                && [ball2.currentColor isEqual:ball1.currentColor]) {
                NSMutableArray *nodeArray = [colorCount objectForKey:key];
                if (!nodeArray) {
                    nodeArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:5];
                }
                [nodeArray addObject:ball2];
                [colorCount setObject:nodeArray forKey:key];
                [nodes removeObjectAtIndex:j];
            }
        }
        NSMutableArray *nodeArray = [colorCount objectForKey:key];
        if (nodeArray) {
            [nodeArray addObject:ball1];
            [colorCount setObject:nodeArray forKey:key];
        }
    }

    [colorCount enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(id key, id obj, BOOL *stop) {
        NSArray *array = obj;
        if (array.count >= 5) {
            // Add code to join the nodes here
            NSLog(@"color: %@ count: %ld", key, array.count);
        }
    }];
}
```

Comment: thanks for the effort. but this is not what I exactly wanted. the nodes touching should form a path.

Comment: I can modify it to do that

Comment: I would be appreciated if you do that. I can compare it mine and inspire from it. thnx already.

Comment: I updated code based on your comment. It should work with any number of sprites.

Comment: Thanks again. Also I have achieved what I want with my algorithm. Right now I will compare yours version with mine and check differences between recursive and normal approach.

Comment: I've updated the code to correct a logic error. You no longer need to set the sprite's name property.